# How to debug exception in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have this piece of code:

```
try {
    System.out.println("????????????????????????????????");
    request.login(username, password);
    System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + e.getMessage());    
 e.printStackTrace();            
}
```

where  request is HttpServletRequest
output is:

```
????????????????????????????????
12618 ERROR org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper  - Unexpected error occurred
```

how I can debug this piece of code and solve where is the problem ?

Comment: The stacktrace schould tell you more about the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make weblogic form autentication in wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902134/how-to-make-weblogic-form-autentication-in-wicket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stacktrace will tell you what type of exception it is. In your IDE, set an Exception breakpoint to catch this type of exception (see links below). Now, debug again, and the execution will stop at the exact spot where the exception is thrown.

- [Eclipse: Add Exception Breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/breakpoints/ref-addexception_viewaction.htm)
- [IntelliJ Idea: BreakPoints](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/breakpoints.html)
- [NetBeans: FaqDebuggingExceptionBreakpoint](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingExceptionBreakpoint)