# weblogic disable authentication

Tags: weblogic, wicket

I have established a WebService on my weblogic 10.3 BEA server, and have tried accessing it through SOAtest only to find that it gives me the error: Recieved HTTP response Code: 403 Forbidden. I appreciate that weblogic is securing my webservice ;) but in the context of what I'm doing I would like to allow anonymous access to this specific webservice. This means that I would like any client to be able to access the SOAP communications of this webservice

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you could try:

From the weblogic console

```
Home -> Domain -> Web Applications -> Turn on "Allow All Roles"
```

From the weblogic console make sure no roles or policies are set in

```
Home -> Deployments -> <your deployment> -> Security
```

In your web.xml deployment descriptor set

```
role-name="*"
```

That said, the default behavior of weblogic (if you haven't changed it to a secure port, etc etc) is to allow anonymous access to web apps so maybe your deployment is specifying roles even though you don't think it should be. Check all of the .xml files in your .war/.ear to see if restrictions are in place.

As a last ditch effort you should check this link: [How to make weblogic form authentication in wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902134/how-to-make-weblogic-form-authentication-in-wicket)

Comment: Thank you, also this post was useful to me : https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1106432

Answer (score 0):

Please look for 'security-constraint' tag inside web.xml to see if there is any CONFIDENTIAL user data constraint. If there is, SSL needs to be enabled on your application server.